# Altair: How to align axis in layered plot?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to create an overlay plot of a binary grid map and a simple line plot. However, when creating a layered plot, the axis are not aligned and the plot becomes unreadable. Ideally, I'd like to have both plot share a single axis so that the line coordinates match the map coordinates.

Here's a basic snippet of my attempt:

```
import torch as th
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

xv, yv = th.meshgrid(th.linspace(-10, 10, 100), th.linspace(-10, 10, 100))
o_map = th.zeros_like(xv)
o_map[40:60, 40:60] = 1  # add obstacle centred on origin
map_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": xv.flatten(), "y": yv.flatten(), "z": o_map.flatten()}
)
map_chart = (
    alt.Chart(map_df)
    .mark_rect()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("x:O", axis=alt.Axis(format=".2")),
        y=alt.Y("y:O", axis=alt.Axis(format=".2")),
        color="z:N",
    )
    .properties(width=500, height=500)
)

x = th.linspace(-5, 10, 100)
line_df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": 0.2 * x ** 2 - 3})
line_chart = alt.Chart(line_df).mark_line(color="red").encode(x="x:Q", y="y:Q")

layer_chart = map_chart + line_chart
```

The resulting plots are as following:

[Line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XINO9.png)

[Binary map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TL6y.png)

[Layered plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gvmp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the x and y channel data type in `map_chart` from 'O' to 'Q' the axis should be aligned automatically.

```py
...
map_chart = (
    alt.Chart(map_df)
    .mark_rect()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("x:Q"),
        y=alt.Y("y:Q"),
        color="z:N",
    )
    .properties(width=500, height=500)
)
...
```

- Update: use `mark_square` instead of `mark_rect`

It seems that `quantitative` data type doesn't play very well when marker is `rect` (e.g. referring to the official example [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_heatmap.html#gallery-simple-heatmap), if you change the `type` of `x` and `y` to `quantitative`, the heatmap doesn't look right, see below).
[image]

So if `rect` is not a must-have marker, I would suggest you choose `square`. As long as your grid is dense enough and the marker size is large enough there won't be empty gaps left between markers, effectively what you want.
[image]

Comment: You're correct, however for a more complicated example, like a grid of squared obstacles, that does not work.
In that case, only one square on each column is displayed.

Comment: @LucasBarcelos can you provide an example together with a picture showing what you meant exactly?

Comment: Sure!

You can add a second obstacle to the plot:

`o_map[40:60, 70:90] = 1  # add second obstacle on the same X coordinate`

And the resulting plot using your code snippet still shows only one obstacle: [result](https://imgur.com/a/x7yaYZr)

Comment: **_Note_** I've changed the line plot to `line_df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": 0.1 * x ** 2 - 3})` so everything is on the same scale.